# How to make a  drawable  hidden when calling Drawable.draw(canvas)?

Tags: android, drawing, visibility, drawable

I find that calling `Drawable.setVisible(false, false)` has no effect.

Does calling `Drawable.setVisible(false, false)` cause a drawable to be hidden the next time `Drawable.draw(canvas)` is called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the interim, i dug around in the sdk code and i'm not 100% confident about this, but it looks the visibility property is only used in drawables for animation purposes. also, if visibility control is needed, the developer is responsible for implementing that by

(1) calling invalidate() to force a canvas redraw and 
(2) not drawing the drawable to the canvas when the framework calls draw().

basically, to hide a drawable, don't draw it.

Answer (score 5):

I usually set a whole view to [invisible](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) and then invalidate it.  That is just cleaner for my project.  Have you tried setVisible(false, true)?  Maybe it isn't refreshing as expected.

Or possibly you can accomplish the desired effect by setting the alpha of the drawable, try the method myDrawable.setAlpha(0);

Comment: I actually only want to hide a particular drawable within the view, not the whole view.

Comment: did you try setting the params false, true?

Comment: sorry i didn't answer your question the first time.  yes, i set the parameters to false, true.

Comment: ok so maybe you can accomplish the same thing by setting the alpha, try the method myDrawable.setAlpha(0);

Comment: @MikeIsrael edit your answer to include myDrawable.setAlpha(0); I really want to upvote it

Comment: @DawidO thanks for the comment, I updated the answer with the setAlpha approach as well.